# How to guarantee that data from 'fetch' is present

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am doing something like this, where I retrieve the data of a fund which contains an id, then I query the server again using the retrieved id to retrieve data from another table:

```
const [backendData, setBackendData] = useState({})
const [fundData, setFundData] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchFund(){
      console.log("fetching fund...");
      var query = getQueryVariable('fund');

      await fetch(`http://localhost:24424/api/funds?fund=${query}`).then(
          response => response.json()
      ).then(
          data =>{
              setBackendData(data);
          }
      )
  }

  async function fetchData(){
      var fundId = backendData[0]?._id ?? "fundid";

      await fetch(`http://localhost:24424/api/funds/data?id=${fundId}`).then(
          response => response.json()
      ).then(
          data =>{
              setFundData(data);
          }
      )
   }

   fetchFund();
   fetchData();
}, [])
```

The problem is that in the `fetchData()` function, `fundId` is always equal to the fallback value `fundid` when the page first loads, so the server query fails. When using `{fundId}` later on in the page, it works fine as the value is eventually retrieved. How can I tell React to wait for `backendData[0]?._id` to be present before executing the `fetchData()` function?

Comment: Since you're using state use two separate `useEffect`s. The first to get the backend data, and another that has `backendData` as a dependency (so it runs when that state changes) with the other `fetch` operation. If you weren't using state you could `await` the first fetch, and then run the second in one effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate the two function so one depend of the existing of the other your code will look something like this

```
const [backendData, setBackendData] = useState({})
const [fundData, setFundData] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchFund(){
      console.log("fetching fund...");
      var query = getQueryVariable('fund');

      await fetch(`http://localhost:24424/api/funds?fund=${query}`).then(
          response => response.json()
      ).then(
          data =>{
              setBackendData(data);
          }
      )
  }
   fetchFund();
}, [])


useEffect(() => {

    if(!backendData?.[0]?._id) return;
    
    async function fetchData(){
        var fundId = backendData[0]?._id ?? "fundid";
  
        await fetch(`http://localhost:24424/api/funds/data?id=${fundId}`).then(
            response => response.json()
        ).then(
            data =>{
                setFundData(data);
            }
        )
     }

   fetchData();

}, [backendData])
```

Now fetchData will only get called when at least one backendData is available